# Displaying diffrerent data from JSON in two separate tabs

Tags: ajax, json, tabs

I've got two tabs, which have to display data from different films using rotten tomatoes API. My tabs `#tab4` and `#tab5` have data attributes which contains film `id` number, like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="tabs4" id="tab4" data-movie-id="770672122">
```

Then I got this code, which adds same class to both tabs and `$(this)` is supposed to show which data attribute should be taken when tab is clicked.

```
$("#tab4, #tab5").addClass("tab");

$('.tab').click(function(){
    var filmID = $(this).attr("data-movie-id");
```

Then, using this `var`, I make url in ajax request:

```
   $.ajax ({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/" + filmID + ".json?apikey=[your_api_key]",
        success: dataHandler,
        crossDomain: true
    });
```

Problem is that only `#tab4` content is displayed. Even if I delete `addClass` and add `click` function to only `#tab5`, its data is displayed in the fourth tab content. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="tabs4" id="tab4" data-movie-id="770672122">
        Tab 4
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="tabs5" id="tab5" data-movie-id="10591">
        Tab 5
    </a>
</li>


<div class="tab-content" id="tabs4">
    <div class="film">
        <div class= "film-info">
            <div id="title"></div>
            <br>
            <div id="year">
              <span class="first-word">
                Year: 
              </span>
            </div>
            <div id="studio">
              <span class="first-word">
                Studio: 
              </span>
            </div>
            <div id="synopsis">
              <span class="first-word">
                Synopsis: 
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="poster" class="poster"></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="tabs5">
    <div class="film">
        <div class= "film-info">
            <div id="title"></div>
            <br>
            <div id="year">
                <span class="first-word">
                    Year: 
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="studio">
                <span class="first-word">
                    Studio: 
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="synopsis">
                <span class="first-word">
                    Synopsis: 
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="poster" class="poster"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```